# Materialize CSS - Dynamically add options to select list

Tags: jquery, html, select, materialize

I'm trying to popular a select list in Materialize CSS with data from an array of objects.

I currently have a select list:

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});

function populateSelect() {
  $('.select-person').empty();

  people.forEach(function(person, index) {
    var option = $('<option></option>');
    option.val(index);
    option.text(person.name);
    $('.select-person').append(option);
  })

  $('.select-person').material_select();
}
```

```html
<select class="white-text select-list select-person">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select a person</option>
</select>
```

Now this sort of works and populates the select list with the people data, but it in addition it messes up the caret and pushes the icon down, and also shows the options outside of the select list in addition to the ones inside the select list.

How can I fix this? I'm using Materialize v0.100.2.